# Is there any way to leave window in the foreground in GNOME Shell when it loses focus?

Tags: gnome, window, focus

My ideal situation:

Given a full screen window w/o focus (in the background) and a smaller window w/ focus (in the foreground), I'd like to be able to mouse over the full screen window to give it focus (ie: focus-follow mouse) so I could do something like entering texts, but leave the smaller window visible in the foreground. The full screen window should move to the foreground when clicked.

Is this possible or already implemented somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Right click the title bar and activate **Always on Top**.

Comment: The full screen window should move to the foreground when clicked. Also, I'd like for this to be the default behavior, w/o having to select anything from a menu.

Comment: Hm, but then how are you going to see the smaller window if the full screen window gets the foreground? You said you wanted the smaller window to be visible even when the fullscreen window had focus. Or you want a partial focus on mouse over that lets the smaller window be on top, and a full focus on click that makes the fullscreen window be in the foreground?